# Maximum number of stl::list objects

Tags: c++, stl

The problem is to find periodic graph patterns in a dataset. So I have 1000 timesteps with a graph(encoded as integers) in each timestep. So, there are 999 possible periods in which the graph can occur. Also I define a phase offset defined as (timestep mod period). For a graph which was first seen in the 5th timestep with period 2, the phase offset is 1.

I am trying to create a bidimensional array of lists in C++. Each cell contains a list containing graphs having a specified period and phase offset. I keep inserting graphs in the corresponding lists.

```
list<ListNode> A[timesteps][phase offsets]
```

`ListNode` is a class with 4 integer variables.

This gives me Segmentation fault. Using 500 for the size runs fine. Is this due to lack of memory or some other issue?

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean `std::list<ListNode> A[1000][1000];`?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the editing part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're running out of stack space. Try allocating it on the heap, e.g. through `std::vector`, and wrap in `try ... catch` to see out of memory errors instead of crashing.

(Edit: Don't use `std::array` since it also allocates on the stack.)

```c
try {
   std::vector<std::list<ListNode> > a(1000000);   // create 1000*1000 lists
   // index a by e.g. [index1 * 1000 + index2]
   a[42 * 1000 + 18].size(); // size of that list

   // or if you really want double subscripting without a wrapper function:
   std::vector<std::vector<std::list<ListNode> > > a(1000);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {   // do 1000 times:
       a[i].resize(1000);                // default-create and create 1000 in each
   }
   a[42][18].size(); // size of that list

} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << "Caught " << typeid(e).name() << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::array` allocates on the stack, so it's not a solution.

Answer (score 6):

Probably due to limited stack size.

You're creating an array of 1000x1000 = 1000000 objects that are almost certainly at least 4 bytes apiece, so roughly 4 megabytes at a minimum. Assuming that's inside a function, it'll be `auto` storage class, which normally translates to being allocated on the stack. Typical stack sizes are around 1 to 4 megabytes.

Try something like: `std::vector<ListNode> A(1000*1000);` (and, if necessary, create a wrapper to make it look 2-dimensional).

Edit: The wrapper would overload an operator to give you 2D addressing:

```
template <class T>
class array_2D { 
    std::vector<T> data;
    size_t cols;
public:
    array_2D(size_t x, size_t y) : cols(x), data(x*y) {}

    T &operator()(size_t x, size_t y) { return data[y*cols+x]; }
};
```

You may want to embellish that (e.g., with bounds checking) but that's the general idea. Addressing it would use `()`, as in:

```
array_2d<int> x(1000, 1000);

x(100, 3) = 2;

y = x(20, 20);
```

Comment: A `std::list` is almost certainly larger than 4 bytes, so I think you're on to something.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what do you mean by creating a wrapper?

Comment: @user1404853: added small demo/explanation to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In libstdc++ on a 32 bit system a std::list object [weights 8 bytes](http://ideone.com/mSSkNP) (only the object itself, not counting the allocations it may make), and even in other implementations I don't think it will be much different; so, you are allocating about 8 MB of data, which isn't much *per se* on a regular computer, but, if you are putting that declaration in a function it will be a local variable, thus allocated on the *stack*, which is quite limited in size (few MBs at most).

You should allocate that thing on the heap, e.g. using `new`, or, even better using a `std::vector`.

By the way, it doesn't seem right that you need a 1000x1000 array of `std::list`, could you specify exactly what you are trying to achieve? Probably there are data structures that better fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a two-dimensional array `[1000]`x`[1000]` of `list<ListNode>`. I don't think that's what you intended.

The segmentation fault is probably from trying to use elements of the list that aren't valid.

Comment: Actually I need to create such lists. They work fine while using lower size values. I was trying to use a huge dataset which exceeded 1000 elements in size.

Comment: @user1404853, I think you wanted 1000 lists of size 1000, not 1000000 lists.